# anchor tag not been able to disabled

Tags: javascript, angular

i have a response coming from the backend , in that response i have a status field ,if the status is approved iam disabling the anchor tag but its not working ,i tried to find whats the issue but i couldnt, can anyone tell me how to fix this
ts

```
  this.receipt=this.dataSource.data;
    this.receipts=this.receipt.forEach(element => {
      this.status=element.status
      console.log(this.status);


    });
```

html

```
    <!-- Id Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="id"> Receipt No </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row;let i=index"> <a [attr.disabled]="status =='APPROVED' ? true: null" (click)="openCreateReceipt(row)"
              routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
              class="link-class">{{row.id}}</a></mat-cell>
        </ng-container>
```

css

```
a.disabled {
  pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `disabled` attribute for `<a>` tag. Look the [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

!UPDATED

You can use do this instead

```
<a status="FALSE" href="#">Name</a>
```

now in your CSS do like this

```css
a[status="FALSE"] {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
  /* rest of your disable code */
}
```

So the theory is, pass a custom attribute `status` and give a value to it. Then use it to style

Comment: @Md.Moshfiqaur Rahman yeah but i searched in google ,they are using the disabled property in anchor tag

Comment: For that, it is best to use classes. Create two classes one to enable, one to disable and set programmatically one of the classes when needed.

Comment: i think based on the attribute only we can able to disable, if it is possible using classes can you show me how to do it,thank you

Comment: I have added the one you are talking about. Updated answer

Comment: @Md.Moshfiqaur Rahman, hey i used  the code what you are suggested ,but it is diabling all the data in the table

Comment: ``` <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="id"> Receipt No </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row;let i=index"> <a receivableStatus='APPROVED' (click)="openCreateReceipt(row)"
              routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
              class="link-class">{{row.id}}</a></mat-cell>
        </ng-container>```

Comment: because we are accessing all the <a> tag. Give the <a> tag a class name and in the css instead of a tag use the class name

Comment: @Md.Moshfiqaur Rahman  ,no bro im using the one anchor tag only actually im using the table ,based on the condition of the status ,i have to diabled , i tried with the button  ithink the condition itself not working  thats why its not disabling

Comment: If it is possible to make a codesandbox then it will be better for me to give the answer. But the solution I Gave is working fine here. if your anchor tag has the right attribute and the value it will work for sure

Comment: @Md.Moshfiqaur Rahman,can we move this discussion to chat , since im a new user im not able to move this into chat room

Comment: I can't also open it

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anchor tag has class "disabled". You are targeting "disabled" class on anchor tag.

use css:

```css
a[status='APPROVED'] {
 pointer-events: none;
  cursor: not-allowed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

we can disable the anchor tag based on the class ,
this is the solution

```
   <!-- Id Column -->
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
          <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="id"> Receipt No </mat-header-cell>
          <mat-cell *matCellDef="let row;let i=index"> <a [class.disabled]="row.status=='APPROVED' ? true : null" (click)="openCreateReceipt(row)"
              routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
              class="link-class">{{row.id}}</a></mat-cell>
        </ng-container>

a.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```